# Add Js code for Google measuing checkout in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, requirejs

I want to measure checkout page using tag manager 
Enhanced Ecommerce.

I refered https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout.

How to add this script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            measuringcheckout: 'js/measuring_checkout'
        }
    }
};
```

> **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/measuring_checkout.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       //your Google script
       return function onCheckout()
       {
           alert('Google measuring checkout OK');//just for JS loading test
           dataLayer.push({
             'event': 'checkout',
             'ecommerce': {
               'checkout': {
                'actionField': {'step': 1, 'option': 'Visa'},
                'products': [{
                 'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
                 'id': '12345',
                 'price': '15.25',
                 'brand': 'Google',
                 'category': 'Apparel',
                 'variant': 'Gray',
                 'quantity': 1
               }]
              }
            },
            'eventCallback': function() {
              document.location = 'checkout.html';
            }
           });
       }
});
```

> **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'measuringcheckout'], function($, onCheckout) {
        onCheckout();
    });
</script>
```

**You should also:**

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

I don't test it, but it should work.

Comment: @Prince its throws some error.

Comment: What's that error ?

Comment: 'eventCallback': function() {
              document.location = 'checkout.html';
            }

Comment: Its redirect to checkout.html. after that its throws ..magento2/checkout/checkout.html 404 error

Comment: Its need to redirect checkout.html or other page?

Comment: Idon't know how it works this script, I just gave you how to that script in checkout page, checkout.html doesn't exists in Magento, just keep checkout and remove `.html`

Comment: Ok.. Thanks....